# How can I use this T-SQL query in LINQ / Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, linq, t-sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm only dealing with one database table / entity object:  NodePath.

Given a particular Node, I want to get only a subset of all its NodePaths according to this query:

```
select
    *
from
    NodePath
where
    NodeId = @GivenNodeId and
    Id in
    (
        --active paths
        select
            a.Id
        from
            NodePath a join
        (
                select
                    [Path],
                    max(Created) as Created
                from
                    NodePath
                group by
                    [Path]
        ) b on
        a.[Path] = b.[Path] and
        a.Created = b.Created
    )
```

How can I execute this in my VB.NET application?

```
Dim AllPaths = GivenNode.NodePaths.OrderByDescending(Function(p) p.Created)

Dim ActivePaths = ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a stored procedure, and then add that to your EDMX (model) to be called. Just right click and select "Update model from database", there should be a stored procedures tab. See also [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2007/09/14/how-to-map-stored-procedures-using-the-ado-net-entity-framework.aspx).

Find the stored procedure in the Model Browser.

Right-click it and select Create Function Import.

[Entity Data Model Create Function Import http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/9100/createfunctionimport.gif](http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/9100/createfunctionimport.gif)

Choose what type of entities are returned.  (in this case: NodePath)

Call the function from within your code:

```
Dim ActivePaths = context.ActivePaths(GivenNode.Id)
```

If you wanted to do this without a stored procedure, you'd have to use LINQ or Entity SQL. Or ADO.NET of course :)

Comment: I've updated this answer with more steps.  Thank you, Marcel.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I've translated that SQL correctly, but I can make changes if necessary. This is selecting one `NodePath` for each common `Path` (based on the greatest `Created`), so long as it matches the `NodeId`.

C# Solution:

```
var nodePaths = (from p in context.NodePaths
                 group p by p.Path into g
                 select g.OrderByDescending(i => i.Created).First()
                 ).Where(p => p.NodeId == givenNodeId);
```

VB.NET Solution (I think, not my primary language):

```
Dim nodePaths = (From p In context.NodePaths _
                 Group p By p.Path Into Group _
                 Select Group.OrderByDescending(Function(i) i.Created).First() _
                 ).Where(Function(p) p.NodeId = givenNodeId)
```

Comment: This is a little odd though, as it grabs the NodePath with the greatest Created first, then filters. This appears to be how the SQL query works though, which is why I wrote it like this.

Comment: Also, I wrote this with LinqToSql in mind, but I'm not seeing anything that would cause issues in the Entity Framework.

Comment: Thank you, Ryan.  I've decided to go with Marcel's stored procedure suggestion for now.  I know I must eventually force myself to get far more comfortable with LINQ.

Comment: Sure! Even if you don't feel comfortable having queries like this in your code, it might be interesting to run it (either normally, or with LinqPad) just to see what query it generates compared to your current one.